# How do i locate dispatchEvent methods in magento?

Tags: php, magento, dispatch

say i have found this line

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_is_salable_before', array(
    'product'   => $this
));
```

how do i find the method that is called by `Mage::dispatchEvent`, i have learned that Magento has stuck some of these `Mage::dispatchEvent` lines in but haven't created any methods for them for the purpose of customization so i am also wondering how i will be able to tell the difference between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento there are event listeners that call the methods. The `dispatchEvent` basically releases a flare so to speak and there are "observers" waiting for this signal, which then call the methods you assign.

You assign the observers of events/flares to call methods using your module's `etc/config.xml`.

You can read this nice tutorial on how to do it [**here**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

If you are interested in knowing what events there are by default, there is a link on that page: [Magento Event List](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?cache=cache&media=http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/_media/dispatcheventlist.xls) (Which doesn't work) sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Marshall's answer gives a good summary of how events work, and how to assign event observers.

However, if you want to find exactly what methods are called by a particular event dispatch, you'll need to do a bit more work.

One tool that comes in very handy for these sorts of things is [`n98-magerun`](http://netz98.github.com/n98-magerun/). It is a command-line to that allows you to perform many of the routine development tasks relating to Magento with ease.

One of the `n98-magerun` commands is `dev:module:observer:list`. It lists every single observer that's registered in all `config.xml` files accross the application.

You can then search/grep the output for the particular event you're looking for, in this case `catalog_product_is_salable_before`.